# Which Nvidia GPU is rendering the display? (SUSE)

Tags: nvidia, suse

In a SUSE machine with multiple GPUs, is it possible to quickly and programmatically tell which GPU (or GPUs) are rendering displays?

The goal is to automatically detect a card eligible/available for use in debugging.

(One cannot use cuda-gdb on a card that is rendering a display, and guessing is... inelegant.)

Answer (score 2):

Non-programmatically, you can use the NVIDIA control panel (if you have a proper nvidia linux driver loaded for your GPUs, you should [just be able to do](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.17/README/nvidiasettings.html) `nvidia-settings` at a terminal to launch the control panel) to determine which GPU is connected and/or rendering to which display.

Programmatically, it's a bit more complicated because you have to define what you mean (programmatically) by "the display".  But as an example, if you have only one display (thus there is no confusion about which one you have in mind), you can use the NVIDIA API that [nvidia-settings is built on](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-settings/) (NVCtrl), to get at the information [programmatically](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=137306).

And with CUDA 5.5, you can use cuda-gdb on a GPU that is rendering a display, but it requires a cc 3.5 or better GPU and [some extra setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Na9-V52kNSQ).

I suppose another approach (possibly simplest, programmatically) would be to use the [NVML](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml) function [nvmlDeviceGetDisplayMode](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML_cuda5/nvml.4.304.55.pdf)

NVML is the api that the utility `nvidia-smi` is built on.  So you can manually query the display mode of devices that way as well.

Since you've edited to indicate a programmatic approach, I think the first method I would recommend is the NVML one.  If you have no other selection criteria, simply cycle through the GPUs until you find one for which display mode is disabled.  If you want to be sure that a particular GPU has it's display mode disabled, be sure to exclude it from [your X configuration](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/how-faq-forums/advanced-how-faq-read-only/438705-opensuse-graphic-card-practical-theory-guide-users.html) for your specific distro (e.g. be sure it is not referenced in `xorg.conf`, on many linux distros)

Comment: The ultimate goal is a programmatic method.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.